# School database Design Diagram

Tags: database-design

I want to design a database for school the output of the system have to be like this : 
[image: The system Output]

So I design this Database [image: Database Design]

Is there any tips or  notes that may make it better .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, `Person` represents the generic information about any person tied to this system; students, teachers, other school employees.  Information that's in `Person` wouldn't need to be repeated in `Student` (name, address, DOB).

I would add the student's current grade/class (kindergarten through high school) to `Student`. Let's call that `StudentClass`; we'll use it later.

Also - you may need an intermediary table to go with `MarkType` and `Mark`.  I would think you'd need something to indicate the total available points for each item (as shown in the headers of your output). `MarkType` makes sense as is. I would have `Mark` as a table indicating a particular exam, quiz, homework assignment (etc.). So, it would need:

- `MarkID` (primary key)
- `MarkType`
- `SubjectId`
- `MarkValue` - the points this specific item is worth (for example 10 points).

Then, I would have `StudentMarks`:

- `StudentMarkId` (primary key)
- `MarkId`
- `StudentId`
- `Mark` - the points earned on this specific item, by this student (for example one student might get 9 points out of the possible 10, other might only get 5).

I would also be inclined to decouple `Term` and `Subject` - there may be subjects that are only offered for one term. Similarly, different instructors may provide a different mix of assignments, and assign different values to a given assignment than another instructor. I would create two new tables:

`Instructor`:
 - `InstructorId` (primary key)
 - `PersonID` (foreign key to `Person`, where name, address, DOB would be)
 - ... (other information specific to a given instructor, regardless of the subject they're teaching, or the term/year they're teaching it in)

`Course`:
 - `CourseId` (primary key)
 - `SubjectId`
 - `TermId`
 - `InstructorId`

`TermId` would be removed from `Subject`, and `CourseId` would replace `SubjectId` in `Mark`.

Another note: it might make sense to specifically tie a student to a course. that could be called....

`CourseRoster`:
 - `StudentCourseId` (primary key)
 - `StudentId`
 - `CourseId`
 - `StudentCurrentClass` (the value of `StudentClass` at the time this student was in this class).

In that case, replace `StudentId` with `StudentCourseId` in `StudentMarks`.

This would even let you identify if there were exams/quizzes/assignments that a particular student in a particular course had no mark for.

UPDATE: Based on your comments, I added some fields to track the student's current "class" (K through high school), and their class when they took a specific course. consists of hard-coded values (in the US, there's kindergarten plus 12 years of education before university, so "K" and "1" - "12" would work here), the `Class` table shouldn't actually be needed.If you need to establish explicit classes for some reason, then the `Class` table would still be needed. I would reverse it, though - one class has multiple students, so put `ClassID` in the `Student` table. Note: you may want to consider tying each `Class` to a specific `Term`, as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :) ,,
Person Table is for students + Teachers + employees as well as employers.
Class Table : this system is supposed to handle a student  data from KG to High school as our education system in the school we have a 15 class .
another issue that I will have if we have more than one same class I mean class 2 (A) , class 2 (B) , what should I do !

Comment: What the different between Mark value in Mark table and Mark in StudentMarks Table !!

Comment: `Mark_Value` is the maximum points available for this test/quiz/assignment. `Mark` is what this particular student got out of the total available.

Comment: Updated - should handle Class now (you've still got some options there).

Comment: **The eeducation year is 2 terms first one and second one So I will put the TermId in 
Subject table.
 did you mean the mark is of MarkValue 
then where should I create the TotalMarks Column ?
As you see I have Person Id and StudentId that means the student will 
have 2 IDs , Is it good to delete the StudentId and use the PersonId
as a F.K.? 
Please explain that to me Is it necessary to have a primary key in any 
Table created ?
I know that by practicing anyone will be better but I want to be good in
designing database can you give some title of books to read .**